# visual effects of Command-type functions do not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mirror

Hello I am new to mirror and networking in unity and I have a problem in my game. When I call [Command] type functions, I have the impression that they are executed but no visual element appears (particle animation).

Here's my player script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Mirror;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerSetup))]
public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar]
    private int numberPlayerBattleRoyal = 1;

    private bool MatchMakingStartOk = false;

    [SyncVar]
    public List<Player> playersBattleRoyal = new List<Player>();

    [SerializeField]
    PlayerShoot playerShootToDisableOnLobby;

    [SyncVar]
    public bool wantedPlayToBattleRoyal = false;

    private int siuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerUI;

    public bool wantedPlayToBattleRoyal2 = true;

    [SerializeField]
    private string BattleRoyalScene;

    public bool isOnBattleRoyal;

    [SyncVar]
    private bool _isDead = false;
    public bool isDead
    {
        get { return _isDead; }
        protected set { _isDead = value; }
    }


    [SerializeField]
    private float maxHealth = 100f;

    [SyncVar]
    private float currentHealth;

    public float GetHealthPct()
    {
        return (float)currentHealth / maxHealth;
    }

    [SyncVar]
    public string username = "Player";

    public int kills;
    public int deaths;

    [SerializeField]
    private Behaviour[] disableOnDeath;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] disableGameObjectOnDeath;

    private bool[] wasEnabledOnStart;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject deathEffect;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject spawnEffect;

    private bool firstSetup = true;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip hitSound;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip destroySound;

    public void Setup()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            //Changement de caméra
            GameManager.instance.SetSceneCameraActive(false);
            GetComponent<PlayerSetup>().playerUIInstance.SetActive(true);
        }

        CmdBroadcastNewPlayerSetup();
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdBroadcastNewPlayerSetup()
    {
        RpcSetupPlayerOnAllClients();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcSetupPlayerOnAllClients()
    {
        if (firstSetup)
        {
            wasEnabledOnStart = new bool[disableOnDeath.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < disableOnDeath.Length; i++)
            {
                wasEnabledOnStart[i] = disableOnDeath[i].enabled;
            }

            firstSetup = false;
        }


        SetDefaults();
    }

    public void SetGameBattleRoyal(List<Player> playersInGame)
    {
        foreach (Player players in playersInGame)
        {
            players.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        isOnBattleRoyal = true;
    }

    public void SetDefaults()
    {
        isDead = false;
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        //Réactive les scripts du joueur
        for (int i = 0; i < disableOnDeath.Length; i++)
        {
            disableOnDeath[i].enabled = wasEnabledOnStart[i];
        }

        //Réactive les GameObject(graphismes) du joueur
        for (int i = 0; i < disableGameObjectOnDeath.Length; i++)
        {
            disableGameObjectOnDeath[i].SetActive(true);
        }

        //Réactive le collider du joueur
        Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();
        if (col != null)
        {
            col.enabled = true;
        }

        //Apparition du systeme de particules d'apparition
        GameObject _gfxIns = Instantiate(spawnEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(_gfxIns, 3f);
    }

    private IEnumerator Respawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GameManager.instance.matchSettings.respawnTimer);
        Transform spawnPoint = NetworkManager.singleton.GetStartPosition();
        transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
        transform.rotation = spawnPoint.rotation;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        Setup();

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(isOnBattleRoyal == true)
        {
            if(siuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu < 1)
            {
                DontDestroyOnLoad(playerUI);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(BattleRoyalScene);
                StartCoroutine(Respawn());
                siuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu++;
            }
        }
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Lobby")
            {
                playerShootToDisableOnLobby.enabled = false;
                if (MatchMakingStartOk)
                {
                    CmdMatchMaking();
                }
            }
            else if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "SampleScene")
            {
                playerShootToDisableOnLobby.enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        CmdDontDestroyPlayerOnLoad();
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdDontDestroyPlayerOnLoad()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(playerPrefab);
        DontDesstroyMyPlayerOnLoad();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void DontDesstroyMyPlayerOnLoad()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(playerPrefab);
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdAddPlayerToBattleRoyal()
    {
        RpcAddPlayerToBattleRoyal();
        MatchMakingStartOk = true;
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcAddPlayerToBattleRoyal()
    {
        playersBattleRoyal.Add(this);
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdMatchMaking()
    {
        if (playersBattleRoyal.Count >= numberPlayerBattleRoyal)
        {
            List<Player> playersInGameBR = new List<Player>();
            Debug.Log(playersInGameBR);
            for (int i = 0; i <= numberPlayerBattleRoyal; i++)
            {
                playersInGameBR.Add(playersBattleRoyal[i]);
                RpcFinishedMatchMakingBR(playersInGameBR);
            }

        }
    }

    public void RpcFinishedMatchMakingBR(List<Player> PlayerInGameList)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i <= PlayerInGameList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (isLocalPlayer)
                {
                    SetGameBattleRoyal(PlayerInGameList);
                }
            }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcTakeDamage(float amount, string sourceID)
    {
        if (isDead)
        {
            return;
        }

        AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(hitSound);

        currentHealth -= amount;
        Debug.Log(transform.name + " a maintenant :" + currentHealth + " points de vies.");

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(destroySound);
            Die(sourceID);
        }
    }
    private void Die(string sourceID)
    {
        isDead = true;

        Player sourcePlayer = GameManager.GetPlayer(sourceID);
        if(sourcePlayer != null)
        {
            sourcePlayer.kills++;
            GameManager.instance.onPlayerKilledCallBack.Invoke(username, sourcePlayer.username);
        }

        deaths++;

        //Désactive les conponents du joueur lors de sa mort
        for (int i = 0; i < disableOnDeath.Length; i++)
        {
            disableOnDeath[i].enabled = false;
        }

        //Désactive les GameObject(graphismes) du joueur lors de sa mort
        for (int i = 0; i < disableGameObjectOnDeath.Length; i++)
        {
            disableGameObjectOnDeath[i].SetActive(false);
        }

        Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();
        if (col != null)
        {
            col.enabled = false;
        }

        //Apparition du systeme de particules de mort
        GameObject _gfxIns = Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(_gfxIns, 3f);

        //Changement de caméra
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            GameManager.instance.SetSceneCameraActive(true);
            GetComponent<PlayerSetup>().playerUIInstance.SetActive(false);
        }

        Debug.Log(transform.name + "est eliminé");

        StartCoroutine(Respawn());
    }
}
```

Thank you if you can sort this out for me and sorry if my English isn't great but I use a translator.

Comment: And the console say : Command Function System.Void Player::CmdXXX() called on Player1 while NetworkClient is not ready.
This may be ignored if client intentionally set NotReady.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object,UnityEngine.Object)
Mirror.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal (string,int,Mirror.NetworkWriter,int,bool) (at Assets/Mirror/Core/NetworkBehaviour.cs:316)
Player:CmdXXX ()
Player:Setup () (at Assets/scripts/Player.cs:97)
Player/<Respawn>d__34:MoveNext () (at Assets/scripts/Player.cs:171)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)